# Lua/Love - My printed text keeps disappearing

Tags: for-loop, lua, love2d

I am making a hangman game. Right now I need it to be that if the user presses the key of a letter that is in the preset word, it shows up on the screen in the correct order. For example : when the word is "word" pressing "w" would show w _ _ _ on the screen. Then if d is pressed next it would say w _ _ d. However, this isn't happening. Instead it is showing _ _ _ d when d is pressed after w and erases the w from the screen. I am thinking my problem might be related to my for loop in love.draw or something in key.pressed. I am very stumped so any help would be greatly appreciated! I have copied love.keypressed, love.draw, and other important variables below in the order they are called in my code.

Code:

```
wrongCount=0
randomWord = "word"
wordSpots = {}
wordList = {}
numBlanks = string.len(randomWord)
Ltext = " "

function love.keypressed(key)
    pressed = key
    if key == "escape" then --one of the letters in the word
        love.event.quit()
    elseif key == "a" or key == "b" or key == "c" or key == 'd' or key == "e" or key == 'f' or key == 'g' or key == "h" or key == "i" or key == 'j' or key == 'k' or key == 'l' or key == 'm' or key == 'n' or key == "o" or key == "p" or key == 'q' or key == 'r' or key == 's' or key == 't' or key == 'u' or key == "v" or key == "w" or key == 'x' or key == 'y' or key == 'z' then
        Ltext = pressed
--guess function
        LrandomWord = string.lower(randomWord) --ensure no problems with capitalization
        letterWrong=0
        wordSpots = {}
        for i=1, #LrandomWord, 1 do
            c = LrandomWord:sub(i,i)
            if Ltext == c then
                Cguess=Ltext
                table.insert(wordSpots, i)
            else
                letterWrong= letterWrong + 1
            end
        
        end
        if letterWrong == #LrandomWord then
            wrongCount = wrongCount + 1
        end
    end
end

function love.draw()
    push:apply('start')
    love.graphics.clear(40/255,45/255,52/255,255/255)
    love.graphics.printf(Ltext, 0, 80, VIRTUAL_WIDTH+30, "center")
    love.graphics.printf("Welcome to Hardcore Hangman!", 0, 10, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, "center")

    --hanging pole
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2 -80, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 +40, 160, 5) --base
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2 - 60, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 - 80, 5, 120) --pole
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2-60, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 -80, 45, 5) --upper base
    love.graphics.rectangle('fill', VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2 - 15, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 -80, 5, 15) -- small down pole
    
    for i=1, 4,1 do
        love.graphics.rectangle('fill', VIRTUAL_WIDTH/2-4, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 - 15*i, 20,5)
    end
        -- creates blanks for guessing
    blankPos = VIRTUAL_WIDTH/6
    for i=1, #randomWord,1 do
        love.graphics.rectangle('fill', blankPos, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 +80, 25, 5)
        blankPos= blankPos + 35
    end
    push:apply('end')
    tableLen = #wordSpots
    love.graphics.printf(tableLen, 0, 80, VIRTUAL_WIDTH+30, "center")
    for i=1, tableLen, 1 do
        spot = wordSpots[i]
        love.graphics.print(Cguess, blankPos*spot + 10, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/2 +80)
    end
    
end
```

Comment: Every time you call `love.keypressed`, you set `wordSpots = {}`, erasing any previous achievements. Remove this line from the function.

Comment: Tweaked a few things to get those letters to line up  --  https://github.com/doyousketch2/hangman  --  I'll type an explanation this afternoon.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff to unpack here.  In brief:

```lua
    elseif key == "a" or key == "b" -- etc.
        Ltext = pressed -- <<< overwrites Ltext
--guess function
        LrandomWord = string.lower(randomWord) --ensure no problems with capitalization
        letterWrong=0
        wordSpots = {}  -- <<< clears wordSpots
```

That's probably (part of) your problem.  Looking further, it seems you decided to rewrite `wordSpots` every time because just below that you use

```lua
            if Ltext == c then
                Cguess=Ltext
                table.insert(wordSpots, i)
            else
```

even though `wordSpots` isn't "array-like". You're also not giving it a value to insert, so `table.insert` will shift everything to the right of `i` one spot further right and then insert `nil` - both things that you don't want.  You probably just want to say `wordSpots[i] = Ltext`.

Further, in the drawing function:

`tableLen = #wordSpots` - given that you're only setting single values in `wordSpots`, `wordSpots` is not an array and has no real length - so most of the time, you'll get 0.  If you want to use `#`, you should initialize `wordSpots` with `false` in all slots - e. g.

```lua
randomWord = "word"
wordSpots = {}
for i = 1, #randomWord do  wordSpots[i] = false  end
```

but alternatively (that's probably the better approach) you could iterate up to `#randomWord` instead of `#wordSpots`, or (yet another approach) iterate over `pairs( wordSpots )` if you just want to get all the `(position,letter)` pairs from `wordSpots` (they may occur in any order! but that should be fine here.)

Once you dealt with all of these, it should hopefully work.  (But that's guessing really, because I can't really follow your code... Also, I can't run your code because some parts seem to be missing.  For your next question, try to (a) make it runnable, (b) try to keep as much stuff `local` as possible (else you risk spooky (inter)action at a distance), and (c) remove stuff that doesn't matter - e.g. drawing the arch.  There's also lots of "noise" that you could clean up first - e.g. `for i=1, tableLen, 1 do` doesn't need the `,1` at the end - 1-sized steps are the default - and removing all of these extra characters would make it easier to see what actually matters.  Looking at the whole code sample, it looks like at some point you added a bug, that confused you, and then you added more and more stuff on top to try and fix it and just made it more confusing.  Go the other direction, *remove* stuff until you see why something does (not) work.)

---

Completely unrelated style remark:

You probably noticed how `elseif key == "a" or key == "b" or key == "c" or` ... is "a bit" inconvenient.

There's a nice pattern for handling inputs:

```lua
typed_letter = function( key )
     -- body of the elseif goes here
end

keys = {
  escape = love.event.quit,
}
for key in ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):gmatch "." do -- copy to a thru z
  keys[key] = typed_letter
end

function love.keypressed( key )
  local action = keys[key]
  if action then  return action( key )  end
end
```

That turns the static manually written `elseif` chain into a dynamic data structure that's easy to generate or modify.  (E.g. once you pressed a letter, you could disable it so that pressing it another time does nothing - just by removing it from the table; of course in your next round you'll have to re-copy the slots back in.  You can also replace the whole table with a different one if you add something like a menu, and you don't have to change `love.keypressed`.)

---

Your naming convention is also confusing.  What does the 'L' prefix mean? What's 'C' for?  If you want to use "name spaces", you can just use *actual tables!*  (And then you can also give them better names...)